# deploy flask app to amazon linux 2 ec2 instance

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2

I have seen lot of examples on how to deploy a Flask web app to AWS, but all of those examples are using Ubuntu or Red hat instances of the EC2.

Could any one give me the steps to deploy the flask app to an EC2 instantiated from an Amazon Linux 2 (free tier), and using Python3

**update**

David Buck, thanks for that link, but I am trying to use httpd with mod_wsgi; after going through so many google searches I came up with the following steps:

```
yum install python3-devel httpd-devel gcc
pip3 install mod_wsgi
mod_wsgi-express module-config >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

but with the last command I am getting `mod_wsgi-express: command not found`

once I pass the above step, I can continue with setting up the flask application

Thanks

Comment: Are you coming unstuck at any particular point? Does this help https://thecodinginterface.com/blog/flask-aws-ec2-deployment/

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following steps and got the flask application served from an amazon ec2 instance (Amazon Linux 2 AMI t2.micro)

Login to the ec2 instance via ssh, and run the following commands:

```
01 sudo su
02 yum install python3-devel httpd-devel httpd gcc git
03 pip3 install mod_wsgi
04 mod_wsgi-express start-server
```

the above command didn't work, but it worked after restarting the instance

```
05 mod_wsgi-express module-config >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

again this didn't work; kept getting permission denier error, even when I run with sudo; so I piped to a temp file, and copied the contents of the temp file into the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

The contents of the temp file should like the following

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py37.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/usr"
```

restart the http service and make sure everything is ok

```
06 systemctl restart httpd
```

now for setting up the flask application

```
07 pip3 install flask
08 car /var/www
09 git clone https://github.com/nshathish/flask-lab2.git
10 cd flask-lab2
11 nano flask-lab2.wsgi
```

enter the following contents into the above file

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/flask-lab2")
from app import app as application


12 sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/flask-lab2.conf
```

now copy the following content into the above file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName flask-lab2.myserver.com
  ServerAdmin root@nshathish.com1
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask-lab2/flask-lab2.wsgi
  WSGIDaemonProcess flask-lab2
  <Directory /var/www/flask-lab2>
      WSGIProcessGroup flask-lab2
      WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

final check

```
13 curl http://localhost
```

and if you got `Hello World` for the above command everything is working fine

if anyone can shed some light into why I couldn't run step 5, it would be really useful; also any improvements to the above steps are much welcome